# android-security. - Leaked GCP API KEY

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

We are getting this error message when publishing app update:

> Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details.

I can follow the instructions and restrict the API Key for Android App by entering package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint, but my question is will this somehow affect Google Sign In as the app is available to production.
Like for instance any issues through logging in or something ?

Still haven't tried to perform the instructions due to concerns that it might prevent Google Sign In from working

Comment: Which API keys are you using in your app?

Comment: Credentials API Key